# XML & XSD validation failed: Element has both a 'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xsd

I have an XML file and an XSD file to validate. When i validate , it shows following error.

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-element.3: **Element 'UC4' has both a
>   'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child. Only one of these is
>   allowed for an element.**

**XML File:**

```
<UC4Execution>
        <Script>JOB_NAME</Script>

        <UC4 Server="UC4.com" Client="123" UserId="123" Password="*****" >
        </UC4 >

</UC4Execution>
```

**XSD File :**

```
        <xs:element name="UC4Execution">
                <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>

                    <xs:element name="Script" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="UC4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="Server" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="Client" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="UserId" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                        <xs:attribute name="Password" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>

                </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
```

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is exactly where the error message says it is:

```
<xs:element name="UC4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="Server" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Client" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="UserId" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Password" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

You can't have both `type="xs:string"` and a nested `complexType` for the same `element`.

If you want the `UC4` element to have just attributes and no nested text content then remove the `type` attribute

```
<xs:element name="UC4" minOccurs="0">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="Server" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <!-- ... -->
```

If you want it to have *both* attributes *and* string content

```
<UC4 Server="UC4.com" Client="123" UserId="123" Password="*****">content</UC4>
```

then you need a nested `complexType` with `simpleContent` that extends `xs:string`

```
<xs:element name="UC4" minOccurs="0">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="Server" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Client" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="UserId" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="Password" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```