# The xs:extension causes my element to stop enforcing its type

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have a simple element in an XSD file "strict" that only acepts boolean, however when I use `xs:extension`, the type is no longer enforced.

Here it is declared without attributes:

```
<xs:element name="strict" type="xs:boolean"/>
```

And xml is enforced properly. I.e.,:

```
<strict>false</strict> <!-- succeeds -->
<strict>XXXXX</strict> <!-- fails    -->
```

And with attributes:

```
<xs:element name="strict"> <!-- purposely needed to remove type from this line -->
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:boolean"> <!-- the base is the same as the previous type -->
                <xs:attribute ref="operation"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Then my intentionally bad element here is no longer enforced.

```
<strict operation="none">XXXXX</strict> <!-- succeeds...         -->
<strict operation="none">false</strict> <!-- succeeds as well... -->
```

I noticed that when I am using the `xs:extension` I can no longer put a `type` into my `xs:element` and I assumed the `base="xs:boolean"` would have covered me there, but it doesn't.

My end goal: **allow attributes in an xs:element and also enforce the data type**

Note:
I am using IntelliJ XML/XSD feature to help guide me here by using it's internal lint engine to highlight errors. So it could be possible this is IntelliJ giving an error (or not giving an error) when one is due? Very doubtful since I feel like this is a pretty fundamental aspect of XMLs.

Reference:

- [XML & XSD validation failed: Element has both a 'type' attribute and a 'anonymous type' child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043148/xml-xsd-validation-failed-element-has-both-a-type-attribute-and-a-anonymou)
- Unfortunately, this answer doesn't discuss types.

Update:
With the help of @kjhughes - determined this may be an IntellJ bug. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-257186

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XSD declaration is the correct way to declare that the `strict` element should have an attribute (although you do not include its declaration, so we cannot verify its correctness) and have content of type `xs:boolean`.

See also: [How to define a simple element and attribute in XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31271512/290085)

You are correct to believe that this XML

```
<strict operation="none">XXXXX</strict>
```

should fail.  I have verified that it does fail with a complete example:

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
  <xs:element name="strict">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:boolean">
          <xs:attribute name="operation" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If the above works for you in your validation setup, suspect that you're missing an error regarding missing parts of your XSD (e.g. `ref="operation"`).  If the above does not work, suspect the tool or its configuration.

Comment: Hmm, which validation setup do you use?

Comment: This time it happened to be a simple Xerces-based validation tool, but you'll find the same results with any compliant XSD validator:  Saxon, oXygen XML, etc.

Comment: So the code you posted is pretty much the same thing I had (except the operation attribute is defined directly). This is good, it tells me what I was doing was right however perhaps IntellJ's XML validation tool is buggy?

Comment: Yes, I hoped that you might be able to use this complete, known-good XSD to further your debugging effort.  If IntelliJ has a problem validating that XSD, and you have validation configured properly, the fault would appear to lie with IntelliJ.  However, you should press further to make sure that validation is occuring.  Using the above XSD, be sure that you can force a controlled validation error that can demonstrate that the XSD is being found and applied.  (The absence of a validation error when expected may merely mean that validation is not occuring at all.)

Comment: Reported this bug to IntellJ https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-257186